# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515

Tags: hadoop

Title of the question is the exception which I am getting while installing Hadoop-2.9.1 on windows 10.
After couple of weeks of research, I am unable to find the answer of my titled query.

As per the exception which I am getting, hadoop process is looking for the permissions in the Data directory but I am already running the dfs.cmd and yarm.cmd processes in Administrator mode. So It should not get the permission related problems.

Can someone help me on it.

Comment: What are the permissions on the data directory you're trying to access and what are the user name you're trying to access your directory with

Comment: As I have already mentioned in my post, I am running hadoop processes in administrator mode. 

Apart from it, All users have full controls on this directory.

Comment: did you manage to find reason why it was happening?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to a missing dll. It's related to this [github issue](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/issues/7) and can be fixed by installing [vcredist](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_repair/how-do-i-fix-this-error-msvcp100dll-is-missing/c167d686-044e-44ab-8e8f-968fac9525c5?auth=1).

- x64 version is needed for win x64
- x86 version is needed for win x32

Comment: This worked for Windows 10, Hadoop 2.7, Spark 2.4.