# Problem when calling createOrReplaceGlobalTempView on a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

On my new windows machine, I am using Spark `3.1.1` (using winutils for Hadoop) to create from a csv file a global temp view like so :

```
  DF.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("firstTable");
```

Where `DF` is a `Dataset<Row>` containing the csv data.

I get the following error on the global view creation :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
```

What's the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341528/java-lang-runtimeexception-error-while-running-command-to-get-file-permissions)

Comment: @mck sorry no cups of coffee today